# How to find a basis for an eigenspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the real vector space $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ of real polynomials of grade $\leq 1$. Consider the inner product defined as
$$
\langle p,q \rangle = p(0)q(0)+p(1)q(1)
$$
and the linear operator
$$
L: P_2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow P_2(\mathbb{R})
$$
defined as
$$
L(\alpha + \beta X) = (8 \alpha + 2 \beta) + (\beta - 3 \alpha) X
$$
Then I have to determine all eigenvalues for $L$ as well as the basis for the eigenspaces but I am not sure about the part about eigenspaces. I have found the eigenvalues to be $2$ and $7$

I know that from my book that 
$$
E_L(\lambda) = N(A - \lambda I)
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. Normally I use this to find the eigenspaces and if I do so I get $(-2,1)^T$ is a basis for $E_L(7)$ and that $(-1/3,1)^T$ is a basis for $E_L(2)$. Does this mean now that I have to express these bases as polynomials?

So the desired bases are $p_1 = -2+x$ for $E_L(7)$ and $p_2 = -1/3 + x$ for $E_L(2)$. Have I understood this correctly?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: $L(-2+X)=-14+7X$, sounds good...

Comment: Ok so I just insert whatever I find into L to find the desired polynomials?

Comment: The given inner product is of no use. But what is $N$ ?

Comment: $N$ is defined as the nullspace. This is the notation used in my book which is what I used to find the eigenvectors I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\span}{\textrm{span}\{}$

Yes you have. There is a simple way to verify this.

Since $L(-2+x)=-14+7x=7(-2+x)$ and $L\left(-\frac{1}{3}+x\right)=-\frac{2}{3}+2=2\left(-\frac{1}{3}+x\right)$, $-2+x$ and $-\frac{1}{3}+x$ are eigenvalues of $L$ corresponding to distinct eigenvalues. As the two polynomials correspond to distinct eigenvalues they are necessarily linearly independent.

Now, notice that since $L$ acts on a vector space of $\dim 2$, the eigenspace corresponding to $7$ and $2$ must be $\span 2+x\}$ and $\span -\frac{1}{3}+x\}$ respectively.

If not, suppose for instance that $E_L(7)>\span 2+x\}$. Then, there would be a vector $v\in E_L(7)$ that is linearly independent of $2+x$. Given that the domain of $L$ is of $\dim 2$, we'll have that $E_L(7)=\span v,2+x\}$ equals the entire vector space. But this is clearly impossible, as $P_2(\mathbb R)$ contains, in particular, $-\frac{1}{3}+x$ which  doesn't belong to $E_L(7)$.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

What you are after are the Eigenvectors of the matrix of the transformation,

$$\begin{pmatrix}8&&2\\-3&&1.\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: So as I found that $(-1/3,1)^T$ and $(-2,1)^T$ are eigenvectors for $L$ I insert this into $L$ to find the desired bases (polynomials)?

Comment: @Mathias: no, can't you predict what happens when yo plug into $L$ ?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your answer earlier but I think I got it now.